# Bitlocker is turned off and still preventing dualboot instal

Tags: dual-boot

I can't get ubuntu 20.0 to install because of bitlocker even though bitlocker is turned off on my lenovo think pad E15. I tried to run a parallel install alongside windows 10. I make it right to the end where it tells me that Windows bitlocker needs to be turned off. Then it's just exit from there back to windows 10.

Comment: Please clarify your release; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, and 0 is not a valid month (but there is a 0 in two releases and ten months of the year)

Comment: I've never had to disable bitlocker to install Ubuntu with a pre-existing bitlocker encrypted Windows 10 installation.  Are you sure that you have *unpartitioned* free space where you can install Ubuntu?